# How to display legend in Highcharts Waterfall Chart and make the sum column of waterfall appear in multiple colors?

Tags: javascript, highcharts, waterfall

I tried to find a lot about this but didn't get the answer. For waterfall charts in Highcharts

```
legend: {
     enabled: true
}
```

didn't seem to work. Can you suggest how can we display legend on a waterfall chart? Also, can we have the value of 'y' for every column displayed on top of the column, instead of being displayed on the column? For this change, with most of the other charts,

```
plotOptions: {
  column: {
     dataLabels: {
       enabled: true
     }
   }
 }
```

But this didn't work with waterfall charts.

And finally, is there a way we can make the sum bar look like an aggregate of the other bars in terms of color as well? Like, in the example shown -

[image]

My code is here - http://jsfiddle.net/yr779/236/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what you are asking regards to the legend. Your jsFiddle is showing a legend - you only have one series "Series 1" and it is in the legend. To display the value of each waterfall you need to use the correct [`plotOptions`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.waterfall):

```
plotOptions: {
  waterfall: {
    dataLabels: {
      enabled: true,
      crop: false,
      inside: false,
      overflow: 'none'
    }
  }
},
```

Comment: Thanks for solving this. Can you also tell me how can we obtain multiple colors as shown in the picture pasted above?

Comment: That appears to be using 3 different series of data - not just 3 different points in a single series.

Comment: Ah, got it! Thanks